# Bounded intervals, sequentially compact.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone please give me an example of a bounded interval in R that are not sequentially compact?

A subset E of R is said to be sequentially compact if and only if every sequence x_n in E has a convergent subsequence whose limit belongs to E.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: How about $E=(0,2)$ and $x_n=1/n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval $(0,1)$ with the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. The limit of $a_n$ is $0$ which does not belong to $(0,1)$